# Symfony2 - Website search functionality

Tags: symfony, search

I have a working search function for one entity in my web application.

But I would like to extend this to multiple entities (that are different headers) on my site which contain different posts per entity.

The entities are not related and I would like to use one universal search to query all the entities at once, is this even possible? If not what are my options?

search service

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $results = null;
    $query = $request->query->get('q');

    if (!empty($query)) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $results = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Article', 'a')
            ->select('a')
            ->where('a.title LIKE :search')
            ->setParameter(':search', "%${query}%")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }

    return array(
        'query' => $query,
        'results' => $results,
    );
}
```

searchAction

```
public function searchAction()
{
    // Search code: calling from the service Search
    $query = $this->get('search');
    $posts = $query->search();

    return array(
        'query'        => $query,
        'posts'      => $posts['results'],
    );
}
```

search.html.twig

```
{% block body %}
{{ parent() }}

        <div id="main">

            <div class="article-wrapper">

                {% for post in posts %}
                    {% autoescape false %}
                    {{ include('AcmeDemoBundle:Partial:_post.html.twig', { post: post }) }}
                    {% endautoescape %}
                {% else %}
                    <p>No results found</p>
                {% endfor %}

            </div>

        </div><!-- end Main content -->

        {% block sidebar %}
            {% render controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:sidebar') %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block footer %}
            {% render controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:footer') %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

_post.html.twig

```
<article id="" class="format-standard hentry has-thumbnail">

        <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <img width="230" height="172" src="{{ asset(['images/', post.image]|join) }}" class="" alt=""/>
        </div>

        <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="{{ path('acme_demo_page_show', { slug: post.slug }) }}" title="">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>

            <p class="by-line"> by <a class="author-link" href="" rel="author">{{ post.author }}</a> on {{ post.createdAt|date('l, F j, Y') }}</p>
        </header>
        <!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
            {% autoescape false %}
            <p>{{ include(template_from_string(post.body|truncate(1000))) }}</p>
            {% endautoescape %}
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please try to create your plain SQL
As I understand this should look like

```
"SELECT * FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Article a, AcmeDemoBundle:Post p WHERE a.title = :search or p:title = :search"
```

Then convert it to query builder (not test it but should work)

```
 $results = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Article', 'a')
            ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Post', 'p')
            ->select('a, p')
            ->orWhere('a.title LIKE :search')
            ->orWhere('p.title LIKE :search')
            ->setParameter(':search', "%${query}%")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It does indeed query the other entity, but has a very weird outcome, it now finds the selected post by the title search, then displays it within the posts list if it's an article title. And vice versa if it's a post title (found by search title), it's listed with the articles...? Updated question with the controller/twig files.

Comment: Anyway I can exclude the results from the other entity? And only show the selected title from specific entity?

Comment: Mostly of all your issue connected to case that all entity have same field title. So in your result you get multiple title. Also in result you get combination of result from all tables. So some title from table p can duplicate multiple times for different row in article 'a'

Comment: So the way to resolve this would be to just change the title property name to something different for each?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but you can do raw SQL.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$sql = " 
SELECT *
FROM db1 d1 
LEFT JOIN db2 d2 ON d1.id = d2.id
WHERE  ...
";
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':state_id', $state_id);
$stmt->execute();
$db = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

If they are not related with any ID, I would do two queries and create a new array: `$result1`and `$result2`, something like that.

```
$result_all = array();
foreach ($result1 as $v1) {
    foreach ($result2 as $v2) {
    //array_push or $result_all[] = $v2...
    }
```

Hope it helps.